Override return type hint of function from Python dependency
I am using a dependency that has type hints but doesn't test them and some of them are just broken. For example:
def foo() -> object:
    return {"hello": "world"}

In my code I want to assign the output of that function to a variable that has a dict type.
from dependency import foo

myvar: dict = foo()

With this mypy gives me an error as expected.
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "object", variable has type "dict[Any, Any]")  [assignment]

However if I try and cast it to a dict explicitly that isn't possible either.
from dependency import foo

myvar: dict = dict(foo())

I see the following error.
error: No overload variant of "dict" matches argument type "object"  [call-overload]

What is the right way to tell mypy to ignore the broken type hint from the dependency?

Use typing.cast():
myvar = typing.cast(dict, foo())

If the type used is complex, you may need to quote it:
myvar = typing.cast('dict[str, Any]', foo())


"If the type used is complex, you may need to quote it": Define "complex"? dict[str, Any] shouldn't require quoting, unless Any is not available at runtime.

It depends. For example if you're running Python 3.8 dict[str, Any] will raise a runtime error, even if you have from __future__ import annotations at the top of your file.
